# How to get the right context of the object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a class whose name is `TestClass`. It has a `TooltipDialog`object member and a `testFunc` function.
In `ToolTipDialog`, it has radio button.
It is expected that when user clicks the radio button it execute `testFunc`.
My question is: How do I get the parent context(`TestClass`) when user clicks the radio button ? 
Could should execute something like `TestClass.testFunc()`.
When i tried with `testFunc`, the error was :`testFunc is not defined`
When i tried with `this.testFunc`, the error was `this.testFunc is not a function`

The code of the `TestClass` is as below, the Fiddle link is [js code](https://fiddle.jshell.net/etxx1o0s/3/)

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare","dojo/dom","dojo/on","dojo/_base/lang","dijit/registry",
        "dijit/TooltipDialog","dijit/popup","esri/InfoWindowBase",
         "dojo/_base/array"],
    function (declare,dom,on,lang,registry,TooltipDialog,popup,InfoWindowBase,Array) {
    return declare(  
        InfoWindowBase,
                {
            constructor: function (parameters) {
                //lang.mixin(this, parameters);
                this.son = "";
            },
            //member of the ParentClass
            init: function ( ) {
                var tpContent = '<div id="dp1"><label for="name">first:</label> <input type="radio" id="first" checked value="pri"/>' +
                    '<br><label for="hobby"> second:</label> <input type="radio" id="second" value="sec"/></div>';

                this.inherited(arguments);
                this.son = new TooltipDialog({
                    content: tpContent,
                    onMouseLeave: function (e) {

                    }
                ,
                    onOpen: function (e) {
                    var sHu=dom.byId("first");
                        on(sHu,"click", function(){
                            // this.testFunc();
                        });

                    },

                });

                popup.open({
                    popup: this.son,
                    orient: ["above","below"],
                    around: dom.byId("tpHolder")
                });

            },
            testFunc:function(){
                console.log("testFunc");
            }
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: What is the question? Please review [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @T Kambi said you need to use `hitch`.
But it you case, you need double `hitch`:

```
onOpen: lang.hitch(this, function (e) {
     var sHu=dom.byId("first");
     on(sHu,"click", lang.hitch(this, function(){
          this.testFunc();
     }));
}),
```

The first `hitch` will make `this` to be the `TestClass` in the `onOpen` method, and the second `hitch` will make the `this` of the `onOpen` method being the `this` of the `click` handler.

I fixed the JSFiddle, so you have a look: https://fiddle.jshell.net/etxx1o0s/5/

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help! @ben, @T Kambi

Answer (score 0):

The context of the event will always be the control/node on which the event is occurring, in you case it will be the object : sHu. You can change the context by using the lang.hitch method.

```
on(sHu,"click", lang.hitch(this, function(){
    this.testFunc();
}));
```

It is not required to pass `this`, you can change to any object which you want as the context of the function.

Comment: Hi @T Kambi, I have tried the lang.hitch as above.  Here the "this" points to "Object {id: dijit_TooltipDialog_0}". Here it should be pointed to the "TestClass". I do not know how to hold the TestClass object.